# Word Document prints as two pages when displays as one

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, printing

I have a Word Document I have been working on for training purposes.  It fits all on a single page, it is on Letter layout, it prints out as letter size, yet when it prints, it either crops out what is missing, or when I print it out as a PDF, it publishes it as two pages.

[image: Screenshot of Word]

One line right above where the graphics are is where it crops it, but the printout dimensions don't look the same as in the Word document there is a lot more white space above the bottom margin than what is printing.  I have seen this problem before with another document and I really can't recall how it was resolved.  If I copy and paste it into a new document, the same problem occurs.

The problem does continue even if I do remove the graphics.

Update:

Shown below is the print preview.  It shows the entire document printed as a single page on Letter sized paper.

The printout stops at step 22 on page one, and continues onto page two.

[image: Print Preview]
[image: Print out Page 1][image: Printout page two]

Comment: That screen shot is far too small to read ...

Comment: Did you set your layout size to A4? Maybe it's currently set to a wider size and shrinks the size down to A4 upon conversion.

Comment: Does Print Preview look like the document as viewed in Word, or does it look like the document as printed?

Comment: @music2myear the preview looks like the word document.  only the printout or PDF outputs as two pages, where the first page does indeed go down to the bottom of the page.  the actual word document doesmt which is strange.